# how can i cast void* to int correctly?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

When I'm studying C, I find this program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct Base
{
void* data;
}
int main()
{
struct Base* base = (struct Base*)malloc(sizeof(struct Base));
if(!base) return -1;
int value = 90;
base->data = value;
printf("%d", base->data);
return 0;
}
```

When compiling, output "warning: assignment to void* from int makes pointer from integer without a cast"
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That's not a program you have, it does not compile because you're missing a semicolon.

Comment: Also there is no solving the problem without you telling what needs to be done. But in this case the most sensible thing is to have `int data;` instead of `void *data`. Also never cast the return value of `malloc` -you're missing `#include <stdlib.h>` and hence your program is very much broken.

Comment: copy paste the exact code that you're compiling when posting questions

Comment: Provide a declaration of malloc by doing `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: What you are doing makes no sense.  An `int` is not a `void *`, and attempting to assign an integer value to a `void *` is a disaster waiting to happen.  30 years ago, it was common to treat pointers as if they were integers, and it led to countless programming errors.  Stop perpetuating a decade's old bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

This will solve it. `data` is a pointer, so you need to assign it to the address of the variable:

```
base->data = &value;
printf("%d", *(int*)base->data);
```

If you really mean what you're writing, but just want to get rid of the warning, use this:

```
base->data = (void*)value;
```

But if you're doing that, it's a good sign you're doing something wrong.

Other than that, [Don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/6699433)

Comment: I suppose it's possible, though unlikely, OP is using the address of `data` as the `int` value. `base->data = (void *)value`; `value = (int)(base->data)`.